# How to add space between absolute elements?

Tags: css, nuxt.js, gsap

I'm working on a slider with gsap & nuxt but I can't find a way to add space between the absolute positioned slides. The absolute position is necessary for the animation to work properly. I tried inline-block to the slide and white-space: nowrap to the wrapper but the animation falls apart then.

Here's a minimal demo of the slider: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-star-3y44ig?file=/pages/index.vue

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

UPD 2:
Updating scripts to handle gap between slides with JS (here is part of updated scripts (and here is [fork with updates of your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-moon-7on5s4?file=/pages/index.vue:1263-1867)):

```js
// ...

var percGap = 5; // gap between slides in percentages
var slideWidthWithGap = 100 + percGap;
var slideXPercent = (i) => i * slideWidthWithGap;

gsap.set(slides, {
  xPercent: slideXPercent,
});

var wrap = gsap.utils.wrap(
  -(slideWidthWithGap * 2),
  (numSlides - 2) * slideWidthWithGap
);
var timer = gsap.delayedCall(slideDelay, autoPlay);

var animation = gsap.to(slides, {
  xPercent: "+=" + numSlides * slideWidthWithGap,
  duration: 1,
  ease: "none",
  paused: true,
  repeat: -1,
  modifiers: {
    xPercent: wrap,
  },
});

// ...
```

To add to slide rounded corners, add this to `.slide`

```css
.slide {
  /* ... */
  border-radius: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden; /* crop block outside border */
}
```

---

Like an option, you can use slide paddings to make it visually separated:

with using CSS variables:

```css
.slide {
  --slide-gap: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 1.5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--slide-gap, 0) / 2);
  padding-right: calc(var(--slide-gap, 0) / 2);
}
```

Without CSS variables:

```css
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 1.5);
  padding-left: .5rem;
  padding-right: .5rem;
}
```

Here is [updated CodeSendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-sea-pqkpk3?file=/pages/index.vue:3764-4022).

UPD:
To add rounded corners to slides, update `.slide-content` selector:

```css
.slide-content {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  /* another CSS props */
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to add margin to the slides?

Comment: @NicolasTuomaala probably, but slides positioned by translate with scripts, so adjustments in this case should be related to scripts

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also tried border-radius but wont work.

Comment: @NicolasTuomaala to add border radius to slides add it to .slide-content. I've updated CodeSendbox.

Comment: @NicolasTuomaala I've updated my answer and added example with handling gap between slides with scripts, see UPD2